# 'Boss Baby-esque' - is it legitimate?

Tags: suffixes

That's from the article on 'The Boss Baby' cartoon I've just read:
"... that newborn girl sits up and reveals that she's wearing her own Boss Baby-esque suit and tie..."

What do you think about such derivation - is it correct?
And how would you pronounce this?

Comment: I agree with SovereignSun that -esque is OK to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

It is legitimate. the word **esque** is pronounced **[ɛsk]** and it means *in the style of; resembling; suggesting the style of*

["boss baby"](http://definithing.com/baby-boss/) means *a girl whos plays her cards right and cup cakes with no feelings.* ([Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baby%20boss))

[plays her cards right](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+cards+right) means *to work or negotiate correctly and skillfully.* *To do the correct things to achieve a desired result.*

If this speaks about the new cartoon [The Boss Baby](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3874544/) then *she acts in the style of that very baby from the cartoon.* Or *she is indeed wearing a suit and a tie that resemble those the Boss Baby has.*

Comment: No, it is about the cartoon, 'The Baby Boss'.

Comment: @rdt09 Please include that in the question. It's much more simple that way.